Phase factor in momentum dependent SSH model
I find a small discrepancy in the "conventional" derivation of the SSH model in the reciprocal space. Let me write down the model below using standard notation.
$H_{\rm{SSH}} = \sum_i \big[ t_1 c^\dagger_{A,i} c_{B,i} + t_2 c^\dagger_{A,i+1} c_{B,i} + \text{h.c.}\big]$. (1)
In the "conventional" derivation, the Hamiltonian is expressed with the Fourier transform
$c_{\alpha i}\equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_{i=1}^L e^{ik.x_{i}} c_{\alpha k};\quad \alpha=A,B\,,$
and we get
$H_{\rm{SSH}} = \frac{1}{L}\sum_{ikk'} \big[ t_1 c^\dagger_{k,i} c_{k',i} e^{i(k'-k)x_i} + t_2 c^\dagger_{A,k} c^{}_{B,k}e^{i(k'-k)x_i}e^{-ik'a} + \text{h.c.}\big]$, (2)
which leads to the simplified form
$H_{\rm{SSH}} = \sum_{k} \big[ t_1 c^\dagger_{A,k} c_{B,k}  + t_2 c^\dagger_{A,k} c^{}_{B,k}e^{-ika} + \text{h.c.}\big]$ (3)
where we use the identity: $\frac{1}{L}\sum_i e^{i(k'-k)x_i} = \delta_{kk'}$ (a representation for Kronecker delta at $L\to\infty$).
Thus, the $k$-dependent SSH can be written as
$H_{\rm{SSH}}(k) = \big[ (t_1   + t_2 e^{-ika})\, c^\dagger_{A,k} c^{}_{B,k}+ \text{h.c.}\big]$. (4)
Now, Eq. (2) is flawed in the sense that positions for site $A_i$ and $B_i$ are not the same (both cannot be $x_i$). The positions differ by the sublattice constant $\delta$ (distance between $A_i$ and $B_i$). Thus, the first two terms in Eq. (2) get multiplied by an additional factor $e^{ik\delta}$. Due to the presence of the Hermitian conjugate terms, this factor cannot be absorbed into the hopping amplitudes and $k$ dependent SSH Hamiltonian becomes
$H_{\rm{SSH}}(k) = \big[ (t_1  + t_2 e^{-ika})  c^\dagger_{A,k} c^{}_{B,k}\, e^{ik\delta} + \text{h.c.}\big]$. (5)
Now the only way to say that Eq. (4) and (5) are equivalent is if we consider the transformation (or redefinition): $c^{}_{B,k}\, e^{ik\delta}\to c^{}_{B,k}$.
My question: How is such a transformation physically justified? I understand it won't affect the quantum expectation value (phase gets canceled out in the inner product). Then why do we need to retain a similar phase factor in Peierl's substitution in the presence of a magnetic field? Can these two situations be compared?
